# How do they differ? Tags webserver and web-server

Tags: discussion

I recently applied the webserver tag to my question and noticed that there are two tags: webserver and web-server.  How do they differ?

Answer (score 2):

They don't, and now  [web-server](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/web-server) no longer exists.