# Proposal to merge Instances tag into instance

Tags: discussion, retag-request

The [instances](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/instances) tag seems to be a duplicate of [instance](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/instance). The proposal is to merge [instances](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/instances) into [instance](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/instance) and subsequently remove the [instances](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/instances) tag.

Comment: Actually this kind duplicate tags has been compiled in this thread: [Cleanup duplicate tags: different by hyphenation and pluralization](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/7937/cleanup-duplicate-tags-different-by-hyphenation-and-pluralization). Half of the [original list](http://meta.serverfault.com/revisions/7938/1) has been handled by our ex-mod HN.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[instances](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/instances) was merged into and synonymized with [instance](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/instance).

But really, neither tag is useful; it ought to just be burninated.

Comment: Wow, yeah, that's a pretty suck tag.