# Tag Burnination [tag:instance]

Tags: discussion, tag-burnination

The [instances](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/instances) tag was [recently](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8302/proposal-to-merge-instances-tag-into-instance) merged into [instance](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/instance) and this comment was made

> But really, neither tag is useful; it ought to just be burninated.

It is a pretty useless tag so shall we burninate it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This tag is no longer attached to any questions. In the near future it will disappear automagically in a puff of electrons.

Answer (score 15):

**Yes it's useless lets burninate it**

Comment: I don't think there is anything in this tag... ;)

Answer (score -8):

**No it's not useless leave it alone**